# Multi touch stopped working after latest update

Tags: touchpad

After the latest update, I can no longer scroll using touchpad and key repeating no longer works.  Anyone else have similar issues?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: + 1
I can confirm that it happened to me as well. I also have this problem.

Comment: Same problem here. Disabling Physical Clicking is not really a solution because I like to put it on 'Multitouch'

Answer (score 1):

Well, after disabling "Physical Clicking" in "Mouse & Touchpad" settings and rebooting the system it works perfectly.